# Jackson marshalling with inconsitant data

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm running into a problem with inconstant data coming back from a web service.  When an object doesn't exists, I might get back a boolean back in the response.

Happy Path:

```
{
    "foo": {"msg": bar}
}
```

Unhappy Path:

```
{
    "foo": false
}
```

When a value boolean is returned, I would like store it as a null Foo object but so far I haven't found an good way in Jackson to address this issue.

Mostly what I've done so far was just using the @JsonProperty annotation to map my objects to what json response.

```
 //... Omitted code
 @JsonProperty("foo")
 public void setBar( Bar bar ) {
     this.bar = bar
 }


class Bar {
    String msg;
    // ... Getter and setter below ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  It's not very elegant but it doesn't require any major code rewrites.  I was able to use JsonNode object at my foo property setter.  Still, I'll see if I can come up with something better.

```
@JsonProperty("foo")
public void setBar( JsonNode barJsonNode) {
    if( barJsonNode.isBoolean() ){
       bar = null;
    } else {
        // Magic goes here
    }

}
```